# How can I create a loop in this jQuery code?

Tags: jquery

I am doing repeat this div with php while loop, when I change selectID (selector) and need change rest of the input values. but there are so many selectID so need loop for multiple values.

HTML code here

```
<div id="addPart1">
   <div>
      <select id="selectID" name="item[]" required>
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
         <option>3</option>
      </select>
   </div>
   <div id="descID" name="item_note[]" form="partForm"></div>
   <div>
       <input type="number" id="priceID" name="price[]" form="partForm">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="number" id="qtyID" name="quantity[]" form="partForm">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="number" id="disID" name="discount[]" form="partForm">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input  type="text" id="amtID" name="amount[]" form="partForm">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input type="hidden" id="amt1ID" name="amount1[]" form="partForm">
   </div>
   <div>
      <input id="deleteLine" value='delete'/>
   </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript Code here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // need loop from here where '1' is attached with IDs need to be looped.
   $('#selectID1').on("change", (function() {
       selectedOption = $('option:selected', this);
       $('#priceID1').val(selectedOption.data('price'));
       $('#qtyID1').val(selectedOption.data('quantity'));
       $('#qtyID1').attr("title", selectedOption.data('quantity2'));
       $('#info').html(selectedOption.data('quantity2'));
       $('#disID1').val(selectedOption.data('discount'));
       $('#amtID1').val(selectedOption.data('amount'));
       $('#amt1ID1').val(selectedOption.data('amount1'));
   });
// end loop
});
```

Comment: what you want to be done from above code?

Comment: Please format your question properly and also add the html. Cannot understand what your problem.

Comment: @RangaRS now check

Comment: @AhmadAli the next time you post to SO please make sure you post a question as a title. You don't need to say "thanks in advance", this isn't a forum.

Answer (score 0):

Try as below code. jQuery selector `[id^='selectID']` will select all `select` elements whose `id` starts with `selectID`.

```
$("[id^='selectID']").on("change", (function() {
    selectedOption = $('option:selected', this);
    var index = $(this).attr("id").replace("selectID", "");
    $('#priceID' + index).val(selectedOption.data('price'));
    $('#qtyID' + index).val(selectedOption.data('quantity'));
    $('#qtyID' + index).attr("title", selectedOption.data('quantity2'));
    $('#info').html(selectedOption.data('quantity2'));
    $('#disID' + index).val(selectedOption.data('discount'));
    $('#amtID' + index).val(selectedOption.data('amount'));
    $('#amt1ID' + index).val(selectedOption.data('amount1'));
});
```

**EDIT 1**

As suggested by [cars10m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51372776/need-loop-in-javascript-my-code-is-here-thanks-in-advance/51373698?noredirect=1#comment89719236_51373698) updated and make code short as below.

```
$("[id^='selectID']").on("change", (function() {
    const data = $('option:selected', this).data();
    var index = $(this).attr("id").replace("selectID", "");
    $('#priceID' + index).val(data.price);
    $('#qtyID' + index).val(data.quantity);
    $('#qtyID' + index).attr("title", data.quantity2);
    $('#info').html(data.quantity2);
    $('#disID' + index).val(data.discount);
    $('#amtID' + index).val(data.amount);
    $('#amt1ID' + index).val(data.amount1);
});
```

Comment: You can further shorten your script by doing `const data=$('option:selected', this).data()` in the first line of your anonymous function. You can then address the individual properties of the passed object like `$('#priceID' + index).val(data.price);...` etc..

Comment: @cars10m Thanks for suggestion. Updated my answer.

Comment: @cars10m it should also work but i implement because karan's code already good for me.